Error 404 in Wildfly from (simple) spring-boot-swagger project
I have a question: I try this project:text
It is a simple java-spring-boot project with Swagger UI platform.
I download the zip project, so import (from File\Import of Eclipse Menù) the folder project with Eclipse. After I launch mvn clean install and I have the .jar file (demo-api-service.jar).
But when I insert the jar file in wildfly-folder\standalone\deployments and restart Wildfly, from browser (http://localhost:8080/demo-api-service) I see: 404 - Not Found.
No errors from Wildfly (Wildfly is OK, I can go in ConsoleManagement, ...).
No errors from Wildfly Console Management.
No errors from jar (I see demo-api-service.jar.deployed in wildfly-folder\standalone\deployments).
Why? I don't modify that project!
I have not idea(s).
Wildfly is OK.
I have jar file after mvn clean install
Wildfly restart doesn't have success.
No errors from Wildfly (Wildfly is OK, I can go in ConsoleManagement, ...).
No errors from Wildfly Console Management.

An app server like Wildfly uses .war files. Spring Boot doesn't need an app server since it runs one itself as part of your application--that's why you have a .jar. The two things simply don't work together.

Ok, thanks! But if I create the war file of this project and put it in "webapps" folder of Tomcat server, will I have problems?

As @nitind commented, Wildfly is a server and Spring boot is a server and putting a server in a server doesn't work very well.  What is it you're looking for?  Is it just an API with Swagger/OpenAPI?  If so, I would direct you to this example as it uses Quarkus (itself derived from Wildfly) with built in OpenAPI support.

Ok, thanks!  Now I use Tomcat 10.

Ok, thanks a lot!
Solution: use Tomcat 10 with .war file .
